# User video upload to be played in all browsers

Tags: php, video

I am creating an web application, where user can upload his profile introduction video. I tried searching around to look for tutorials, but did not find any. I have the user video upload part/ code in `PHP`, but my question is that how can I make the video playable in all browsers?

Is there a library for it or application I have to use for that? If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try using a flash video player (renders the video) or html5 video tag if you are not woried for IE9<. Look at http://videojs.com/

Comment: @KA_lin  thank you. Do I need to convert the video after the upload, since as far as I understand you need all the different formats for different browsers?

Comment: Have no idea, it should support multiple formats (read the docs)

Answer (score 0):

try this it's work for you

```
<video controls>
       <source src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/uploads/profile/<?php echo $listdata['SubscriberVideo'][0]['name'];?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

change video path to your path.

Comment: Thank you, but my question actually is that do I need to convert the video after the upload so it can be playable in every browser or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the video to play in most major browsers on most common devices an OS's (all is tricky as there are many small niche browsers), then, as I am guessing you have noticed, you need to be aware of the video formats that different combinations require.

Partly this is because new and better encoding methods emerge over time and are adopted at different times by different browsers etc, and partly it is because the video encoding world is full of patented software and different browsers, OS's etc have different rights and different philosophies around this.

On top of that you need to be aware that the requirements change over time as new devices and new codecs etc are released.

You can narrow things down by restricting yourself to the most recent versions of OS's and browsers, and by using HTML5 playback.

There are several resources that provide some example HTML5 code to support playback across as wide a set of devices as possible - e.g.:

- http://v4e.thewikies.com

As you can see you do need to convert the uploaded video into several different encodings and packaging format to achieve maximum coverage.

You can do this sever side by using a package like ffmpeg, open source video manipulation software:

- https://www.ffmpeg.org

There is a PHP wrapper library for ffmpeg which may be worth looking at if your server is PHP based:

- https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Having said all the above, if you want a simpler solution that will play back in nearly all browsers at this time, the mp4 format (MP4 container and H.264 codec) will probably meet your needs. You can check current coverage using links such as this one (make sure you use a well known reputable source as this areas changes frequently):

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats